# How do I convert tabs to exact number of spaces in bash script?

Tags: bash, tabs

I need to convert a string with tabs to a string with spaces.

But I need to number of spaces to match the tabbing so that the format is identical.

I need this because Gnuplot labels don't like tabs.

So I want:

```
A      very       fat      cat
```

Which is `A\tvery\tfat\tcat`, converted to:

```
A      very       fat      cat
```

with spaces, and not to

```
A very fat cat
```

EDIT 1

I think I misunderstood the problem:

```
$ cat -T Aggregate/summary.txt | head -n1
      Date        Pnl     AnnPnl  Days  AvTrds  AveVol  AveDur TDays      Pnl/$  AvPnl     StdDev       MAXD  Shrpe
```

But when I assign to a variable the spaces are lost:

```
$ FF=`cat Aggregate/summary.txt | head -n1`; echo $FF
Date Pnl AnnPnl Days AvTrds AveVol AveDur TDays Pnl/$ AvPnl StdDev MAXD Shrpe
```

Comment: if u use `"` around `$FF` every thing be OK: `echo "$OFF"`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `expand` command:

```
~$ cat >c
a       fast    cat     nrstaui e
~$ expand c>d
```

When using `cat -A`, you can see that spaces are used (tabs are represented by `^I`):

```
~$ cat -A c
a^Ifast^Icat^Inrstaui^Ie$
~$ cat -A d
a       fast    cat     nrstaui e$
```

EDIT:
If you assign the line to a variable, you have to use double quotes to see the differences:

```
~$ F=$(cat c)
~$ echo "$F" |cat -A
a^Ifast^Icat^Inrstaui^Ie$
~$ echo $F |cat -A
a fast cat nrstaui e$
```

Same problem with spaces:

```
~$ F=$(cat d)
~$ echo "$F" |cat -A
a       fast    cat     nrstaui e$
~$ echo $F |cat -A
a fast cat nrstaui e$
```

Comment: Thank you. But I think I misunderstood my own problem - please see EDIT 1

Answer (score 0):

<strike>There's a utility just for this: `expand`.

`expand [file]` (or from standard input) should do the trick.</strike>

Re: your edit,

use **quoted** POSIX-style command substitution rather than backticks:

`FF="$(cat Aggregate/summary.txt | head -n1)"; echo "$FF"`

Answer (score 0):

**UNDERSTANDING WHY YOUR TAB SPACES ARE CONVERTED INTO SINGLE SPACE CHARS**

Let us rename your variable to "variable" and assign the following to it

```
variable ="      Date        Pnl     AnnPnl  Days  AvTrds  AveVol  AveDur TDays      Pnl/$  AvPnl     StdDev       MAXD  Shrpe"
```

**[1]** when you do

```
echo $variable
```

your output will be

```
Date Pnl AnnPnl Days AvTrds AveVol AveDur TDays Pnl/$ AvPnl StdDev MAXD Shrpe
```

**Reason:** echo is seeing your variable not as  one big string but several strings spearated by a space or more than one space character.This is because bash is not seeing this variable as one string since the variable is not enclosed in double qoutes.

**[2]** when you do

```
 echo "$variable"
```

your output will be

```
      Date        Pnl     AnnPnl  Days  AvTrds  AveVol  AveDur TDays      Pnl/$  AvPnl     StdDev       MAXD  Shrpe
```

**Reason:** This is because you enclose your variable with double quotes which bash will automatically interpret as one big string. As a result echo will print this one big string.